# About the symbol $p^{\frac{1}{p^\infty}}$ in perfectoid geometry

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to read papers about perfectoid geometry and I'm wondering that what the symbol $p^{\frac{1}{p^\infty}}$ means. An example is that：
Let $W(k)$ be the Witt ring of a perfect residue field $k$. Then $K^{o}=W(k)\langle p^{\frac{1}{p^\infty}} \rangle$ is a perfectoid valuation ring.
I'm not well prepared for perfectoid theory except for a little number theory and algebraic geometry. Symbols like that could bother a lot. Which book can I refer to?

Comment: Happy to know the birth of [perfectoid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectoid_space)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a similar answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4628572/a-basic-example-of-perfectoid-field), which I partially re-produce here:

To be precise: let $\mathbf C$ be the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathrm{Frac}\ W(k)$.

Now, inductively construct $p^n$-th roots of $p$ as follows: when $n=0$, let $x_0:=p$. For $n\ge1$, let $x_n$ be a root of the polynomial $X^p-x_{n-1}=0$, which has a solution in $\mathbf C$ since $\mathbf C$ is algebraically closed. This produces a *compatible* system of $p^n$-th roots of $p$: $\{x_n\}_{n\ge0}$.

Then, $W(k)\langle p^{1/p^\infty}\rangle$ denotes the completion of $W(k)[\{x_n\}_{n\ge0}]\subset\mathbf C$.