# A basic example of perfectoid field

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have read in many places that one of the most basic examples of perfectoid field is the completion of $\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/p^\infty})=\cup_{n\ge 1}\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/p^n}).$ However, I am not sure what exactly does $\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/p^n})$ mean. Does it mean adjoining all the $p^n$-th power roots of $p$, or just one of them? As $\mathbb Q_p$ does not have a primitive $p^n$ root of unity, I believe there is a difference.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Only one of them. That $\Bbb{Q}_p,\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty}),\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty},\zeta_{p^\infty}),\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^\infty})$ are perfectoid is a bit obvious: $O_K/p$ is a ring of characteristic $p$ so $(\sum_j a_j)^p=\sum_j a_j^p$.

Comment: @reuns So $\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/p^\infty})$ is obtained from $\mathbb Q_p$ by adjoining a compatible choice of $p$ power roots of $p$ to $\mathbb Q_p$. In other words, $\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/p^\infty})=\mathbb Q_p(a_0,a_1,\dots),$ where $a_0=p$ and $a_{n+1}^p=a_n.$ Am I interpreting your comment correctly?

Comment: @reuns I believe $\mathbb{Q}_p$ isn't perfectoid since it is discretely valued

Comment: To be precise, $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty}),\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty},\zeta_{p^\infty}),\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^\infty})$ aren't perfectoid either as they aren't complete. Their completions are perfectoid though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise: let $\mathbb C_p$ be the completion of $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$.

Now, inductively construct $p^n$-th roots of $p$ as follows: when $n=0$, let $x_0:=p$. For $n\ge1$, let $x_n$ be a root of the polynomial $X^p-x_{n-1}=0$, which has a solution in $\mathbb C_p$ since $\mathbb C_p$ is algebraically closed. This produces a *compatible* system of $p^n$-th roots of $p$: $\{x_n\}_{n\ge0}$.

Now, we can construct the field $\mathbb Q_p(\{x_n\}_{n\ge0})$, and denote the completion as $K$. Now $K\subseteq\mathbb C_p$ is perfectoid, since it is a complete topological field with topology induced by a nondiscrete valuation of rank $1$ (namely, the one restricted from $\mathbb C_p$), and $K^\circ$, the completion of $\mathbb Z_p[\{x_n\}_{n\ge0}]$, and on the quotient
$$K^\circ/p\cong \mathbb Z_p[\{x_n\}_{n\ge0}]/p\cong\mathbb F_p[\{X_n\}_{n\ge0}]/(X_1^p=0,X_n^p=X_{n-1}),$$
the Frobenius is surjective.